# Extract trigger words from safetensors file

Tags: python, safe-tensors

With many `.safetensors` files associated to different LoRA authors sometimes specify "trigger words".
I've been trying to extract find the way to extract them from `.safetensors` file but I cannot find them. They are not present in metadata section and according to documentation I cannot think of other place where those can be.

On the other hand, I know that those trigger words are working, because I am getting image generated when I'm providing them.

I thought that something like this will work:
from safetensors import safe_open

```
tensors = {}
with safe_open("lora.safetensors", framework="pt") as f:
   print(f.metadata())
```

But it seems the access is more complicated. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adapting from https://huggingface.co/docs/safetensors/metadata_parsing#python:

```
import json
import struct

with open("lora.safetensors", "rb") as f:
    length_of_header = struct.unpack('<Q', f.read(8))[0]
    header_data = f.read(length_of_header)
    header = json.loads(header_data)

print(header)  # should be a dict that contains what you need
```